# How to effectively test randomness in item ordering?

Tags: automated-testing, test-strategy

We have a function that introduces randomness in item ordering, e.g.:

- the order in which a number of given items are presented to a user is random

For this scenario, there needs to be automated test, I am thinking:

- Compare the configured item order against the actual presented item order, if they are different, the test will pass.

But there is always a chance that the randomised order happens to be identical with the configured order, e.g.:

- We have configured 5 items to be presented to a user, the chance for them to be presented exactly the same order as they are configured is `1 in 5*4*3*2*1`; for 10 items, the chance is `1 in 10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1`; there is always a tiny chance this automated test will fail.

Is there any certain way to test against randomness?

Comment: +1, interesting question,  however IMHO you cannot test randomness with certainty.

Comment: Can;t you have a retry mechanism , if it is equal then refresh the session once more ?

Comment: @PDHide, retry would work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: Isolate the randomness.

You can check this example from Dave Farley where isolated Time: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuDIYk9GBpE&t=1872s

Separate the randomly sorting behavior from the displaying and from the entity definition, using polymorphism.

[image]

Then you can validate each one of these parts in isolation:

- When you want to validate the sorting, you simply inject test-controlled items;
- When you want to validate the displaying, you provide a set of test-controlled items and a test-controlled fake of the sorting mechanism, with static behavior that you test know about;
- If you want to validate what constitutes the items, you won't need either a display nor a sorting mechanism, since these are external to the items.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Test randomness at the unit level using a Chi Test and then verify at the system level that the values properly propagate from the unit to the system.

By random you probably mean [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution), that each value from a list have the same probability to be chosen.

To decide if something is uniformly distributed and have a meaningful result you need to collect enough samples and then do a mathematical statistical test, or simply eyeball them on a graph. The math is not too complicated, and deciding on "enough" is also simple but both belongs to math stackexchange, [this could give you](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435/is-there-a-simple-test-for-uniform-distributions) a starting point [or here](https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/%7Exmeng/Course/CS6337/Note/master/node43.html), but I suppose many languages have ready mathematical functions to help you with that, [even Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/chitest-function-981ff871-b694-4134-848e-38ec704577ac) have a ready Chi Test function.

As to the practicality of such a test, collecting enough results on an end to end test would probably be too slow and cumbersome, the best would be to run a test that collect the chosen values at the unit level and verify randomness there